PIL Image to PixMap Error on QImage Conversion
The following code block:
class MDraw(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MDraw, self).__init__(parent)
        self.data = None
        self.width = 0
        self.height = 0
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.width = event.size().width()
        self.height = event.size().height()
        self.draw(self.data)
    def draw(self, indata):
        self.image = QImage(self.width, self.height, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.image = QImage(self.width, self.height, QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
        self.image = QImage(self.width, self.height, QImage.Format_Alpha8)
        self.image = QImage(self.width, self.height, QImage.Format_RGB32)
        qpainter = QPainter(self.image)
        bbush = QBrush(QColor(90,0,0))
        qpainter.setBrush(bbush)
        qpainter.drawRect(20, 20, 80, 80)
        qpainter.end()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(self.image)
        self.pixmapItem = QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.pixmap)
        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        scene.addItem(self.pixmapItem)
        self.setScene(scene)

Works fine when expanding the widget size, but produces artifacts when shrinking?


Shortly after posting the question I found the answer.
QImage is created with uninitialized data.
Adding this cleared it up:
self.image.fill(0)
